# not.toEqual() returning true dispite different value at key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I'm trying to test if two objects are different by using the function .not.toEqual().

From what I understand, this function is supposed to do a recursive comparison on the values of my object. Despite this, I can't seem to get the result I expect.

This is an extract of what has been printed out in my terminal.

```
expect(received).not.toEqual(expected)
```

> Expected value to not equal:   {Symbol(impl): {"_entries": [{"name":
>   "_method", "value": "POST"},  Received:   {Symbol(impl): {"_entries":
>   [{"name": "_method", "value": "PUT"},

As you can see the values for "value" are different and yet my test fails.

Comment: what is worng in this. I guess result is correct. `expect(received).not.toEqual(expected)` will return true as both object are different.

Comment: The test fails. Maybe I've misinterpreted something, but I was under the impression that not.toEqual() should pass if the two objects are different

Comment: Yeah. it is not the issue is not.toEqual().

Comment: Looks like it's a [bug](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3347) in Jest which has been fixed but not yet available in the latest release (20.0.4).

Answer (score 6):

For the given values:

> {Symbol(impl): {"_entries": [{"name": "_method", "value": "POST"},
>   Received: {Symbol(impl): {"_entries": [{"name": "_method", "value":
>   "PUT"},

```
expect(received).not.toEqual(expected)// should return true
expect(received).toEqual(expected)// should return False
```

Comment: FAIL  src/modules/theme.test.js
  ● createFormData › should not have a method param different from that which was entered (PUT)

It's returning false for me and I can't pinpoint why

Comment: @JuEast what is test case. `expect(received).toEqual(expected)` will return false as both values are different.

Comment: is a comparison between two FormData objects, one where the method is POST and the other PUT. My test case is basically expect(formDataPost).not.toEqual(formDataPut)